# Magento 2.2.4 - Source class "\amazonClient" for "amazonClientLogger" generation does not exist

Tags: magento2.2.4

I am upgrading Magento 2.2.3 to 2.2.4 and got this error when running the command `setup:di:compile` after successfully running `setup:upgrade`.

```
[RuntimeException]
Source class "\amazonClient" for "amazonClientLogger" generation does not exist.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weird but got fixed by running following commands in the order:

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

Comment: This is the kind of thing about M2 that scares me. Too often the solution is to try variations of compilation steps.

Comment: I have no clue why but it worked for me aswell - error popped up from nowhere and got resolved by this answer

Answer (score 0):

I had same Issue, While installing `zip with sample data`.

I've resolved it my **PHP Version to 7.1.x**

Before PHP was 7.0.x, Don't know why Magetnto 2.2.4 doesn't seems to be work with PHP 7.0.x.

As After i switched to 7.1.x it installed successfully..

Hope it will help others..!!